What does "zap" mean here?
What does "zap" mean here:

Reading that in the book, I was like Jamie and I are going to this place, they are going to zap me and we are going to learn something really really fast.

https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx7iGfgquC0oe022FBOQwTAOEoYRvqiSDc?si=mequWveIdojV-ceI

The speaker uses the term zap, normally an electric charge, to mean some figurative energy transfer. Zap is onomatopoeic, the sound of an electric shock.

As a transitive verb, AHD defines it as meaning:

To strike (an object or target) with a beam of energy, an electric current, or supernatural power: In the movie, the alien zaps the scientist with a ray gun.

It can be used figuratively to mean:

To have a sudden and powerful effect on:

His ... narrative runs marvelously on and on, zapping the reader with often surprising and ... painful glimpses" (Publishers Weekly).



Rather than saying something simple like, "they are going to do something to me," the host uses "zap". That gives it a futuristic or science fictiony feeling. They're going to do something unexpected or unusual.
